# Fanchart Customisation (vars package)

Tags: r, plot, colors, axis, forecast

I have the following dataset df:

```
price <- as.vector(c(3755,3243,3109,2990,2949,3021,3104,2988,3014,2999,3090,3209,3039,2748,2671,2556,2554,2650,2627,2560))
people <- as.vector(c(4228,4966,4614,4752,4545,4851,4598,4597,4713,4672,4833,4790,4844,4995,5068,4918,4909,4807,5024,4898))
df <- cbind(price,people)
```

Using `library(vars)` I got the following predictions `vecm.pred` using `VAR` modelling:

```
cointest <- ca.jo(df, K = 5, type = "eigen", ecdet = "trend", spec = "transitory")
vecm.level <- vec2var(cointest, r = 1)
vecm.pred <- predict(vecm.level, n.ahead = 6)
```

I want to then use `fanchart` to graph my model and it's predictions. Cutomising the plot to include:

1. Titles
2. y-axis names
3. Visible y-axis ranges
4. Dates across my x-axis
5. Add out-sample points
6. Change the colour of the predictions confidence interval to a red-yellow heatmap (if possible, but not a priority)

I attempted this by first defining my x-axis (note: I also tried making my `tmax <- as.Date("2018-09-01")` to account for my additional 6 `vecm.pred` forecasts, but these did not appear on the fanchart when attempting this):

```
tmin <- as.Date("2016-08-01")
tmax <- as.Date("2018-03-01")
tlab <- seq(tmin, tmax, by="month")
time <- substr(tlab, 0, 7)
```

I then ran my fanchart code below:

```
fanchart(vecm.pred, xaxt="n",ylab = c("Price (€)","Volume"), main = c("Price","People"))

par(new=TRUE)

axis(1, at=seq_along( c( time, rep(NA,6) )), labels=c( time, rep(NA,6)) ,
 las=3, line=-13.5, cex.axis=0.6)

axis(1, at=seq_along( c( time, rep(NA,6) )), labels=c( time, rep(NA,6)) ,
 las=3, line=5, cex.axis=0.6)
```

This gave me the below fanchart:
[image]

This has a number of problems. How would you go about:

1. Ensuring the y-axes only have one name each
2. Ensure all the ticker values for the y-axes are visible
3. Shift the dates to the left so the first observation is "2016-08" (and if possible, include dates for the next 6 forecasts i.e. up to "2018-09")
4. Add two out-sample points to show how my forecasts did in predicting them e.g. `2525`and `2500`for `price`
5. Change the colour of the predictions from the default grey scale to a red/orange/yellow heat scale (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

I took the `fanchart` function from `vars` and hacked it to add some of the functionality you required (questions 1, 3, and 4). Questions 2 and 5 were already possible with the function from the library. The resulting figure is shown below.

[image]

Here is the hacked `fanchart` function, which I have called `fanchart2`. The main modifications were: changing the y axis labels in the loop (question 1), adding the axis to each plot in the loop (question 3), and adding points that were predictions (question 4).

```
#### hacked fanchart function ####
# base function taken from vars packaged
# hacked to allow more input as required for this problem
fanchart2 <- function(x,
                       colors = NULL,
                       cis = NULL,
                       names = NULL,
                       main = NULL,
                       ylab = NULL,
                       xlab = NULL,
                       col.y = NULL,
                       add.preds = NULL,
                       nc,
                       plot.type = c("multiple","single"),
                       mar = par("mar"),
                       oma = par("oma"),
                       lab.at=NULL,
                       lab.text=NULL,...) {
  if (!(class(x) == "varprd")){
    stop("\nPlease provide an object of class 'varprd',\ngenerated by predict-method for objects of class 'varest'.\n")
  }
  if (is.null(colors)){
    colors <- gray(sqrt(seq(from = 0.05, to = 1, length = 9)))
  }


  if (is.null(cis)) {
    cis <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)
  }
  else {
    if ((min(cis) <= 0) || (max(cis) >= 1)){
      stop("\nValues of confidence intervals must be in(0, 1).\n")
    }
    if (length(cis) > length(colors)){
      stop("\nSize of 'colors' vector must be at least as long as\nsize of 'cis' vector\n")
    }
  }
  n.regions <- length(cis)
  n.ahead <- nrow(x$fcst[[1]])
  K <- ncol(x$endog)
  e.sample <- nrow(x$endog)
  endog <- x$endog
  fcst <- NULL
  for (j in 1:n.regions) {
    fcst[[j]] <- predict(x$model, n.ahead = n.ahead, ci = cis[j],
                         dumvar = x$exo.fcst)$fcst
  }
  xx <- seq(e.sample, length.out = n.ahead + 1)
  xx <- c(xx, rev(xx))
  op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
  plot.type <- match.arg(plot.type)
  ynames <- colnames(endog)
  if (is.null(names)) {
    names <- ynames
  }
  else {
    names <- as.character(names)
    if (!(all(names %in% ynames))) {
      warning("\nInvalid variable name(s) supplied, using first variable.\n")
      names <- ynames[1]
    }
  }
  nv <- length(names)
  ifelse(is.null(main), main <- paste("Fanchart for variable",
                                      names), main <- rep(main, nv)[1:nv])
  ifelse(is.null(ylab), ylab <- "", ylab <- ylab)
  ifelse(is.null(xlab), xlab <- "", xlab <- xlab)
  ifelse(is.null(col.y), col.y <- "black", col.y <- col.y)
  if (plot.type == "single") {
    if (nv > 1)
      par(ask = TRUE)
    par(mar = mar, oma = oma)
  }
  else if (plot.type == "multiple") {
    if (missing(nc)) {
      nc <- ifelse(nv > 4, 2, 1)
    }
    nr <- ceiling(nv/nc)
    par(mfcol = c(nr, nc), mar = mar, oma = oma)
  }
  for (i in 1:nv) {
    ymax <- max(c(fcst[[n.regions]][names[i]][[1]][, 3]),
                endog[, names[i]])
    ymin <- min(c(fcst[[n.regions]][names[i]][[1]][, 2]),
                endog[, names[i]])
    yy1 <- c(endog[e.sample, names[i]], fcst[[1]][names[i]][[1]][,
                                                                 2], rev(c(endog[e.sample, names[i]], fcst[[1]][names[i]][[1]][,
                                                                                                                               3])))
    plot.ts(c(endog[, names[i]], rep(NA, n.ahead)),
            main = main[i],
            ylim = c(ymin, ymax),
            ylab = ylab[i],#### question 1 #### modivied ylab to depend on the loop counter
            xlab = xlab,
            col = col.y,
            ...)
    polygon(xx, yy1, col = colors[1], border = colors[1])
    if (n.regions > 1) {
      for (l in 2:n.regions) {
        yyu <- c(endog[e.sample, names[i]], fcst[[l]][names[i]][[1]][,
                                                                     3], rev(c(endog[e.sample, names[i]], fcst[[l -
                                                                                                                  1]][names[i]][[1]][, 3])))
        yyl <- c(endog[e.sample, names[i]], fcst[[l -
                                                    1]][names[i]][[1]][, 2], rev(c(endog[e.sample,
                                                                                         names[i]], fcst[[l]][names[i]][[1]][, 2])))
        polygon(xx, yyu, col = colors[l], border = colors[l])
        polygon(xx, yyl, col = colors[l], border = colors[l])
      }
    }

    #### question 4 ####
    # if a matrix of points at various times in the prediction is sent to the function
    # they will be plotted here
    # standard adjustments to color and pch are possible
    # assumes a matrix of values is given with columns in order of the variables (price=col 1)
    # and NA values are times without prediction and not plotted
    if(is.null(add.preds)==F){
      points(x=xx[2:(length(xx)/2)]
             ,y=add.preds[,i]
             ,col='gray48'
             ,pch=16)
    }

    #### question 3: adding axis to each plot inside the hacked function ####
    # standard modifications can be done to this function
    if(is.null(lab.at)==F){
      axis(1,
           at=lab.at,
           labels=lab.text,
           las=3,
           line=1,
           cex.axis=0.6)
    }

  }
  on.exit(par(op))
}
```

After loading this as a user-defined function, the following code, which is based in your original example, can be run to generate the figure. I was not sure what times were assigned to the predictions so I chose some examples.

```
library(vars)

price <- as.vector(c(3755,3243,3109,2990,2949,3021,3104,2988,3014,2999,3090,3209,3039,2748,2671,2556,2554,2650,2627,2560))
people <- as.vector(c(4228,4966,4614,4752,4545,4851,4598,4597,4713,4672,4833,4790,4844,4995,5068,4918,4909,4807,5024,4898))
df <- cbind(price,people)

cointest <- ca.jo(df,
                  K = 5,
                  type = "eigen",
                  ecdet = "trend",
                  spec = "transitory") 
vecm.level <- vec2var(cointest, r = 1)
vecm.pred <- predict(vecm.level, n.ahead = 6)

tmin <- as.Date("2016-08-01")
tmax <- as.Date("2018-03-01")
tlab <- seq(tmin, tmax, by="month")
time <- substr(tlab, 0, 7)

fanchart2(vecm.pred
          ,xaxt="n"
          ,ylab = c("Price (€)","Volume") #### question 1: see hacked function ###
          ,main = c("Price","People")
          ,add.preds = matrix(c(NA,2525,NA,NA,2500,NA,rep(NA,6)),byrow = F,ncol=2), #### question 4: see hacked function ####
          ,las=1 #### question 2: rotates text to horizontal for easier viewing ####
          ,colors=heat.colors(9) ##### question 5: capability in pre-hacked function ####
          ,lab.at = seq(1,length(tlab)+6,1) #### question 3: see hacked function, 6 from the n.ahead in vecm.pred  ####
          ,lab.text = c( time, rep(NA,6))  #### question 3: see hacked function
)
```